# Combobox rowsource from userform not being picked up over workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combobox within a userform which shows a list of product names from a table in the same workbook. On the form there are 2 labels, one for the HTS code and the other for the material. The captions of these labels are dependent of the product names, done through Vlookup. The combobox works fine as long as you use it in its own workbook. In other books the droplist is empty.

[Rowsource from userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRBFb.png)

An issue I noticed is that the rowsource from the userform doesn't allow me to specify in which workbook it should get its data from. The source doesnt even allow me to select a column from the table, had to specify a range with a name... (table 3 column1).It's pretty annoying always having those blank rows from the table show up in the dropdownlist. Tried leaving the rowsource in userform blank and define it instead in VBA, didn't work either.

[Empty rows from table showing up in droplist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR2UN.png)

Any ideas how to get data from the original workbook to show up and how to define a dynamic range in the userform rowsource?

```
Private Sub Cb_Product_Change()

CB_Product.RowSource = Workbooks("Code Tester").Worksheets("Test_HTS").ListObjects("Table3")

If CB_Product.Value = "" Then
    Lbl_HTS.Caption = "HTS Code: "
    Lbl_Material.Caption = "Material: "
Else
    Lbl_HTS.Caption = "HTS Code: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CB_Product.Value, Worksheets("Test_HTS").ListObjects("Tbl_HTS").Range, 2, False)
    Lbl_Material.Caption = "Material: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CB_Product.Value, Worksheets("Test_HTS").ListObjects("Tbl_HTS").Range, 4, False)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: using the rowsource property to fill a control is risky and often causes problems. It is better to fill them during the forms initialization, using the List property (if you're adding from a table) or by using the AddItem method (if it is only a handful you can hard-code)

Comment: ty for the tip, putting in initialization worked, no more rowsource property! one problem down. The remaining one is that it still only works in the original workbook. so I copied the sheet with the data over to a new book and it worked. So now I know for whatever reason it ignores the workbook you pick and only checks sheets within the book you're currently in. Any idea how to fix this? i used the code from Notus_Panda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to fill your userform combobox at initialization, to list a few:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' This works:
'    ComboBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A11").Value
    Dim myTable As ListObject
' This works:
    'Set myTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
' This (unsaved workbook7 mind you) different workbook also works:
    Set myTable = Workbooks("Workbook7").Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    ComboBox1.RowSource = myTable.ListColumns("Product").DataBodyRange.Address
End Sub
```

Not sure where your "empty lines" are coming from but if need be, you could fill an array (with only the values you want) and then use the first option like Black cat also mentioned. If I missed anything, let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was slowly losing my mind when the initialisation didn't even want to work. didn't realise you had to type UserForm_Initialize() litteraly and not its name like everything else... but now it works without relying on the rowsource property, one problem down. The remaining one is that it still only works in the original workbook. so I copied the sheet with the data over to a new book and it worked. So now I know for whatever reason it ignores the workbook you pick and only checks sheets within the book you're currently in. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I did give you an example of how to do that already. Workbook7 isn't the workbook the userform is in.

Answer (score 0):

Combobox require a `variant array` input for the data to display in the dropdown.

It can be assigned something like this

```
myvar = Workbooks("Workbook_name").Worksheets("worksheet_name").Range("A1:A10")
Userforms("Userform_name").CB_Product.List = myvar
```

Comment: Can also use the `.Value` of the range instead of using the Variant variable